# Why does Cloudproc Juyterhub constantly disconnect?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

When creating a Dataproc instance and connecting via Jupyterhub, it constantly disconnects.  This means any work on a Jupyter notebook in the Jupyterhub connection is lost.  This seems to happen very frequently and appears to happen for many users, not just me (it happened to a class of about 6 people I teach).  Here are the errors that happen (centered around failed to fetch):

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

This seems uncharacteristically poor for Google.  Is there any way to fix it, or is it some fundamental problem with Dataproc and GCP?  I don't have premium support so don't know how to write in to Google directly about it.

Comment: Are you connecting via an SSH tunnel or is this referring to the "Component Gateway" alpha feature?

Comment: I believe Dennis is referring to this documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways#viewing_and_accessing_component_gateway_urls

Comment: Are you using the [Jupyter initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/jupyter), activating it as an optional component, or using a custom installation? How are you attempting to connect via Jupyterhub? As Dennis hints at, there are multiple ways to open ports to a cluster, but the only reliable way to access arbitrary ports on your compute resources without opening up the firewall is to use an [SSH SOCKS proxy](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces).

Comment: This sounds like an error interacting with GCS. It would us investigate if you could provide any stack traces from /var/log/jupyter.log (you can either SSH to the master node or start a console in Jupyter)

Comment: @DennisHuo both result in the same error.

Comment: @BenSidhom it is an optional component installed by checking a box.  I am using the component gateway feature.  I just noticed based on Dennis and Christopher's comments that it's an alpha feature.

Comment: @wordsforthewise So to confirm, when you say "both result in the same error", you mean you also see the error when you connect via a direct SSH tunnel? If this is the case that indeed sounds like a GCS connection error of some sort.

Comment: Yes, both SSH tunnel and the component gateway.

Comment: It sounds like this is a situation that will require more back-and-forth than we can easily do on Stack Overflow. Please send the steps to reproduce to dataproc-feedback@google.com and we will try to investigate.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I just realized that when I was using SSH, I was still using the component gateway address through the SSH tunnel.  So this may only be a component gateway bug, I'll have to check again with the SSH tunnel and accessing jupyter hub directly that way.

Comment: Just a small update:  this seems to be a problem with JupyterHub; when using Jupyter notebooks through the component gateway, everything seems ok.